# How to calculate the sum of values of multiple arrays in node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I've a use case, where I need to find the sum of the values of multiple arrays and return one array. Here the no.of arrays might vary as per the requirements. So I might get dynamic no.of arrays.

Here is my sample data.

```
values:[
   [10,20,30,40,0],[0,0,5,10,15],[3,0,0,0,10]
]
```

In the above sample `values` array, the number of arrays may vary.
But the length of each sub-array are same.

Now I have to return the following result by adding all the values in to one array.

```
values:[
   [13,20,35,50,25]
]
```

So is there any possibility to achieve this kind of expected result?

Comment: Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: `const sum = (arr) => arr[0].map((_, i) => arr.reduce((acc, c) => acc + c[i], 0))` Given that all the items are the same length, pick the first item to loop over. For each of its indices, loop over the `values` array and accumulate the sum for that index in `acc`.

Comment: let arr = [
    [10, 20, 30, 40, 0], [0, 0, 5, 10, 15], [3, 0, 0, 0, 10]
]

let sum = 0;
for (let subArr of arr) {
    for (let ele of subArr) {
        sum += ele;
    }
}
console.log(sum)